# .NET Core 6 web application throwing HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, publish, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I have deployed a .NET Core 6 web application onto a Windows 2022 Server. When I run it from the browser, it throws an  HTTP Error 500.19 with an error code of 0x8007000d. It is saying that my `web.config` is malformed, and to delete the malformed XML element from my `web.config`.

I have

- Installed the .NET 6 hosting bundle
- Checked the event viewer, and there are no events for when the error is thrown
- Verified that the .NET 6 runtime version on the server matches my development machine
- Checked the permissions on the directory where I am deploying
- Checked the permissions for the user running the application pool in IIS
- Changed the hostingModel attribute from "InProcess" to "OutOfProcess", and back again
- Made sure that the .NET x64 is the only framework installed on the server
- Installed the URL rewriting tool

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\TSSPortal.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 865506a7-3a0b-40ea-aade-ebef0cddc351-->
```

Lastly, if I go to the directory where the application is deployed, and click on the .exe, it brings up a command window that tells me it is listening on port 5000. When I go to the browser and type in http://localhost:5000, the app runs and connects to the local database.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I could try to fix the problem?

Comment: Is anything written to the log file / folder? Does your app have permission to write to it?

Comment: does the other websites under IIS work? try create an empty site and put a test html page and see if it working as intended. if not your web.config, the ApplicationHost.config might have the problem.

Comment: Run a report and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: The only thing that appears in the logs is that there was an HTTP 500.19 error.

Comment: I wrote another SIMPLE app that only has one page (Hello World), and it gives me the same error. The default app that comes with IIS (non .NET) works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

This error can occur because of many different reasons, you can try the following methods:

1. [Installing URL rewriting](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
2. You can try to go step by step and comment out certain sections of web.config and applicationhost.config file and check for application behavior, if the application still continues to throw an error after you have commented a section, then the error is elsewhere. keep doing this and you will finally arrive at the section that is malformed.

Comment: I failed to mention that I have already installed URL rewriting. I will try commenting out sections of the files, and see what I find.

Comment: I have edited my comments to show that URL rewriting has been installed.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.